# I need to input IntFunction such that Collections.toArray(IntFunction<T> generator) returns an array containing n times of values in the collection

Tags: java, java-8

I have a `Set` of `Integer`:

```java
Set<Integer> itemSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
itemSet.add(1);
itemSet.add(3);
itemSet.add(5);
```

I want to convert it into an array of `Integer` where the value of each element in the array is double the value of the corresponding element in original `Set`. According to the above example, the array elements should be:

```
2, 6, 10
```

I tried:

```java
Integer[] itemArr1 = itemSet.toArray((val) -> {
            Integer[] it = new Integer[]{val*2};
            return it;
            }
        );
```

but the values are not getting doubled.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is just convert stream into `IntStream` and multiple each element by 2 using `mapToInt`:

```java
Set<Integer> unique = Set.of(1, 3, 5);
int[] arr = unique.stream().mapToInt(i -> i * 2).toArray();
```

Remember, that `HashSet` is unque unordered set. So you can't predict the otput  order, but you can be sure that in the result array you get unique doubled elementes.

In case you want to get `Integer[]`:

```java
Integer[] arr = unique.stream().map(i -> i * 2).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

`toArray()` here simply produces an array of the desire type and size using the supplied `IntFunction`.  You need to add more logic to get your desired results.  Here are some examples:

```
Set<Integer> itemSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
itemSet.add(1);
itemSet.add(3);
itemSet.add(5);
```

- create the array from the set.
- set each element of that array to twice its current value.

```
Integer[] array = itemSet.toArray(Integer[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
Arrays.setAll(array, i->array[i]*2);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Or the easiest way.

- stream the set
- map esch element to twice the current value.
- Then return as  an Integer[] array.

```
Integer[] array = itemSet.stream().map(i->i*2).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Note:

- The `IntFunction` is used to allocate an array.
- Sets are unordered so the products may appear out of order in the result.

**Update**

To further explain what is happening, here is the default `toArray` method from the source (i.e. the `Collection interface`).  That interface also defines the `Object array` that holds the values of the collection.

```
default <T> T[] toArray(IntFunction<T[]> generator) {
     return toArray(generator.apply(0));
}
```

Notice that a method is invoked that simply uses `0` as the default size of the returned array. Any value `less than or equal` to the set `size` will return the entire `set` contents via the overloaded `toArray` method.  A larger value will fill the returned array with `nulls`.  That method has direct access to the collection, in this case your `set`, so any array allocated in the supplied `IntFunction` is simply ignored (as later shown below).

```
Integer[] itemArr1 = itemSet.toArray((val) -> {
    System.out.println(val);                
    Integer[] it = new Integer[] {val * 2};    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(it)); 
    System.out.println(it);                 
    return it;
});

System.out.println(itemArr1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(itemArr1));
```

prints

```
0                          // the default value of 0
[0]                        // "your" array containing `{val*2}`
[Ljava.lang.Integer;@2a84aee7  // the hashcode of "your" created array
[Ljava.lang.Integer;@a09ee92   // the hashcode of the returned array 
[1, 3, 5]
```

You can see by the above that the hex values are different which depict  different array objects. The returned array is the one that was used, totally ignoring  the one in allocated in the `IntFunction`.  And  this is why you received the same, unchanged values that were in the original set.

Finally, I didn't provide the `stream` solution returning a primitive array as I thought you wanted an `Integer` wrapper array.

Comment: Thanks for answer, both the methods are working. But the Intfunction which as you mentioned in method1 "Arrays.setAll(array, i->array[i]*2);" can double the values in array, is limited to allocation of arrays of required type&size for collections. I was little tempted and expecting Collection.toArray(IntFunction<t>) to accept similiar kind of function.

Comment: @ash_kmt I updated my answer to provide a better explanation of what is going on.  I hope this helps clarify some things.

Comment: @WJS-- Thanks for the indepth explanation.